# Min. iterations drawing regular shape("turtle")

Tags: python, math, geometry, iteration, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to find the least number of iterations necessary to form a regular polygon without my "turtle" (shape) repeating its motion.... and noticed a strange(?) relationship which I cannot pinpoint.

If you run the code below and experiment with different values (NOTE: make sure to replace parameters 'x' & 'n' with actual numbers - of your choice):

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    mike = turtle.Turtle()
    mike.shape("turtle")
    mike.color("yellow")
    mike.speed(100)

    count = 0
    while count < n:                    # replace n with number!
        mike.forward(100)
        mike.right(90)
        mike.forward(100)
        mike.right(90)
        mike.forward(100)
        mike.right(90)
        mike.forward(100)
        mike.right(x)                   # replace x with number!

if __name__ == "__main__":
    draw_square()
```

You will find the turtle moving in a circular(-ish) motion.

For example, you'll notice that when x = 100, min. value of n needed to form a regular shape is 36 (since 100°- 90°=10°; 360°/10°=36).
[when x = 10 e.g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kczka.png)
.

Further tests show:

```
x = 1, (min.) n = 360                   # 360°/1° = 360

x = 5, (min.) n = 72                    # 360°/5° = 72

x = 9, (min.) n = 10*                   # 360°/9° = 10*

x = 10, (min.) n = 9*                   # 360°/10° = 9*

x = 45, (min.) n = 8                    # 360°/45° = 8

x = 90, (min.) n = 1*                   # 360°/90° = 4*

## NOTE: no obvs. solution for n, if x isn't factor of 360....
```

*: Strangely, you must divide the result by 4 to get min. value of n for some numbers.
I had initially thought it was to do with multiples of 9, or four rotations for square, but [above] led me to reject my hypotheses.

So anyone have any better ideas as to a generic rule? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So anyone have any better ideas as to a generic rule?

I believe I've narrowed it down.  There are some errors in your table.  And there are four different types of exception, not just the "divide the result by 4" one.  In fact, across the factors of 360, the exceptions occur more often than the simple `360 / x` rule.  The four exceptions are:

After, `n = 360 / x` if `x` is a:

```
A) multiple of 8 then n *= 4
B) multiple of 4 then n *= 2
C) multiple of 6 and not a multiple of 9 then n /= 2
D) multiple of 2 then n /= 4
```

The rules must be applied in the above order and only one rule can fire.  If no rules apply, leave `n` as it is.  The revised table for all factors of 360:

```
x =   1, n = 360      , 360° /   1° = 360 
x =   2, n =  45 (/ 4), 360° /   2° = 180 (D)
x =   3, n = 120      , 360° /   3° = 120 
x =   4, n = 180 (* 2), 360° /   4° =  90 (B)
x =   5, n =  72      , 360° /   5° =  72 
x =   6, n =  30 (/ 2), 360° /   6° =  60 (C)
x =   8, n = 180 (* 4), 360° /   8° =  45 (A)
x =   9, n =  40      , 360° /   9° =  40 
x =  10, n =   9 (/ 4), 360° /  10° =  36 (D)
x =  12, n =  60 (* 2), 360° /  12° =  30 (B)
x =  15, n =  24      , 360° /  15° =  24 
x =  18, n =   5 (/ 4), 360° /  18° =  20 (D)
x =  20, n =  36 (* 2), 360° /  20° =  18 (B)
x =  24, n =  60 (* 4), 360° /  24° =  15 (A)
x =  30, n =   6 (/ 2), 360° /  30° =  12 (C)
x =  36, n =  20 (* 2), 360° /  36° =  10 (B)
x =  40, n =  36 (* 4), 360° /  40° =   9 (A)
x =  45, n =   8      , 360° /  45° =   8 
x =  60, n =  12 (* 2), 360° /  60° =   6 (B)
x =  72, n =  20 (* 4), 360° /  72° =   5 (A)
x =  90, n =   1 (/ 4), 360° /  90° =   4 (D)
x = 120, n =  12 (* 4), 360° / 120° =   3 (A)
x = 180, n =   4 (* 2), 360° / 180° =   2 (B)
x = 360, n =   4 (* 4), 360° / 360° =   1 (A)
```

The code that generated the above table:

```
EXCEPTIONS = [
    ('A', lambda x: x % 8 == 0, lambda n: n * 4, "(* 4)"),
    ('B', lambda x: x % 4 == 0, lambda n: n * 2, "(* 2)"),
    ('C', lambda x: x % 6 == 0 and x % 9 != 0, lambda n: n // 2, "(/ 2)"),
    ('D', lambda x: x % 2 == 0, lambda n: n // 4, "(/ 4)"),
]

for x in range(1, 360 + 1):
    if 360 % x != 0:
        continue

    n = 360 // x

    for exception, test, outcome, explain in EXCEPTIONS:
        if test(x):
            n = outcome(n)
            exception = f"({exception})"
            break
    else:  # no break
        exception = explain = ''  # no rule applies

    angle = 360 // x

    print(f"x = {x:3}, n = {n:3} {explain:5}, 360° / {x:3}° = {angle:3} {exception}")
```

My rework of your code which I used to test individual table entries:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def draw_square(angle, repetitions):
    mike = Turtle("turtle")
    mike.speed('fastest')
    mike.color("yellow")

    count = 0

    while count < repetitions:
        mike.forward(100)
        mike.right(90)
        mike.forward(100)
        mike.right(90)
        mike.forward(100)
        mike.right(90)
        mike.forward(100)
        mike.right(angle)

        count += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wn = Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("black")

    draw_square(9, 40)

    wn.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice job finding out those set of patterns! - but was there a particularly efficient way you used to find those? I've noticed that your Exceptions list is pre-determined to generate the table      (and sorry for those prev comments they were deleted for being incomplete)

Comment: @mikerover, no, I completed the table and then worked out the exception patterns by examining it.  Not particularly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Further on from the rule-set identified by @cdlane, I've found a quick way to find just the min. number of iterations for any input x - regardless of whether it's a factor of 360 or not - needed to complete a regular shape! (Of course, I've also realised there will not be a minimum value at all for some e.g. when x is 20.75)

.

Below code shows my corrections to faults identified & addition of heading(), to check if mike has returned to its original position after cycle(s):

```
import turtle

def draw_square(angle, repetitions):
    mike = turtle.Turtle()
    mike.shape("turtle")
    mike.color("red")
    mike.speed("fastest")

    count = 0
    while count < repetitions:
        mike.forward(100)
        mike.right(90)
        mike.forward(100)
        mike.right(90)
        mike.forward(100)
        mike.right(90)
        mike.forward(100)
        mike.right(angle)

        count += 1

        print("Turn ", count, "; ", mike.heading())

        if mike.heading() == 0:
            break

    print("Min. iterations needed to complete cycle:  ", count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("black")

    x = int(input("Enter angle: "))
    n = int(input("Enter boundary: "))        # For n, advisably to a v large number; while loop will probably break before reaching its limit anyways

    draw_square(x, n)
    wn.exitonclick()
```